# matplotlib combines box plot and histogram with legend on

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, boxplot

The code in question

```
def plot_hist(plot_data, top_key):
    plot_data = plot_data[top_key]
    plt.title('Number of emails per week by ' + top_key)
    plt.xlabel('Spam emails per week')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    for key in plot_data:
        plt.hist(plot_data[key], bins=20, alpha=0.5, histtype='step', label=key)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def plot_box(plot_data, top_key):
    plot_data = plot_data[top_key]
    data = [list_of_weeks for list_of_weeks in plot_data.values()]
    plt.title('Spam emails per week by ' + top_key, fontsize=20)
    plt.boxplot(data)
    plt.xticks([(i + 1) for i in range(len(plot_data.values()))], \
                 ['%s' % i for i in plot_data.keys()], rotation=80)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(top_key + '/box_plot.png', format='png')
```

`plot_data` is a nested dict. I'm calling the methods like so:

```
plot_hist(plot_data, 'platform') # plot the boxplot for platforms
plot_box(plot_data, 'platform') # plot the boxplot for platforms

plot_box(plot_data, 'obfuscation') # plot the boxplot for obfuscations
plot_hist(plot_data, 'obfuscation') # plot the boxplot for obfuscations
```

The problem comes with `plot_hist(plot_data, 'obfuscation')`. I get the histogram like so:

[image]

See? The box plot from `plot_box(plot_data, 'platform')` is combined with the new histogram.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a new figure between `plot_box()` and `plot_hist()`:

```
plt.figure()
plot_hist(plot_data, 'platform') # plot the boxplot for platforms
plt.figure()
plot_box(plot_data, 'platform') # plot the boxplot for platforms
```

or divide your plotting space in two subplots, in the latter, you will need to change your functions to receive as an input also the `AxesSubplot` object:

```
def plot_box(ax, plot_data, top_key):
```

And instead of calling:

```
plt.hist()
plt.boxplot()
```

you call:

```
ax.hist()
plt.boxplot()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this correctly. But I do not want subplots because of the size of my graphs.

Comment: That does not fix it.

Comment: @KaranGoel Your answer is exactly what I suggested here with "try to create a new figure between `plot_bol()` and `plot_hist()`...

Comment: Oh was it. I thought you meant try drawing a histogram or box plot between the two. I'll delete mine. In any case, can you explain how it works?